# Define "Allow only users in specific security group to share externally" for each site

Tags: sharepoint-online, external

Is there a way to define different groups of users who can share with external users on each site level instead of been set globally?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Theres three groups: owners, members, and visitors. You can assign users to these groups when you create a site.

For team sites, permissions are best managed through the associated Microsoft 365 group or Teams team.

To allow only users in specific security groups to share externally, you can manage this setting.